# How do I alter this javascript to make divs stop in their tracks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I alter this code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwLpf1vr/7/) so that when the button is pressed, the bouncing divs immediately stop in their tracks? I have the button and bouncing divs in place, but they're set to stop in a specific location.

Html

```
<div class="bouncyHouse">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>

  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='2' data-vy='-3'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='-2' data-vy='2'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='5' data-vy='2'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.bouncyHouse {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.bouncer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
  left: 100px;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

javascript

```
 function hitLR(el, bounding) {
    console.log($(el).data('vx'), $(el).data('vy'))
    if (el.offsetLeft <= 0 && $(el).data('vx') < 0) {
        console.log('LEFT');
        $(el).data('vx', -1 * $(el).data('vx'))
    }
    if ((el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) >= bounding.offsetWidth) {
        console.log('RIGHT');
        $(el).data('vx',  -1 * $(el).data('vx'));
    }
    if (el.offsetTop <= 0 && $(el).data('vy') < 0) {
        console.log('TOP');
        $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
    }
    if ((el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) >= bounding.offsetHeight) {
        console.log('BOTTOM');
        $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
    }
}


function mover(el, bounding) {
    hitLR(el, bounding);
    el.style.left = el.offsetLeft + $(el).data('vx') + 'px';
    el.style.top = el.offsetTop + $(el).data('vy') + 'px';

}

function moveIt() {
  $('.bouncer').each(function() {
    mover(this, $('.bouncyHouse')[0]);

  });
};


$htmlBack = $('.bouncer').clone();
moveInterval = setInterval(moveIt, 50);
$('button').on('click', function(){
    console.log(moveInterval);

    if( moveInterval != 0){
        clearInterval(moveInterval);
    $('.bouncer').remove();
    $('.bouncyHouse').eq(0).append($htmlBack);
        $htmlBack = $('.bouncer').clone();
    moveInterval = 0;

  } else {
        moveInterval = setInterval(moveIt, 50);
  } 
});
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mvbs0uu3/

Comment: you should put that as an answer, it looks right.

Comment: @jkris: adding it as an answer would not fit well in SO's mission to *"make the internet a better place"*. The question is too specific and highly unlikely to help anyone, other than the OP, who already got her solution. Besides, JoshCrozier clearly doesn't need the rep. By giving the solution as comment, Josh is allowing Lily to delete the question, while also giving her the answer, so SO wouldn't get one more unhelpful question.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thanks for the insight! Just wondering then, where do highly-specific-answered questions fit in SO?

Comment: @jkris It's a gray area. Going from black: *"Hey, hire a professional developer to do that for you!"* to whiter: *"dress up your very specific problem in a more general suit and prefix it with `"How to..."` and you're in for a perfectly legit, sometimes well received (and up-voted) question*. It all comes down to the ability to provide the perfect [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: This is happening because of the removal and append; After append items are there but there recent top and left position are reset to default;

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem.

Check this fiddle out https://jsfiddle.net/ht3xtto3/.

All you have to do is remove two lines. I commented them out in the fiddle.

Remove:

```
$('.bouncer').remove();
$('.bouncyHouse').eq(0).append($htmlBack);
```

Doing that stops them where they are when you click the button and restarts them when you click it again.

Hope this helps.

Best,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Have a look over this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/itzmukeshy7/j38asdh3/ :)

```js
function hitLR(el, bounding) {
  if (el.offsetLeft <= 0 && $(el).data('vx') < 0) {
    //console.log('LEFT');
    $(el).data('vx', -1 * $(el).data('vx'))
  }
  if ((el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) >= bounding.offsetWidth) {
    //console.log('RIGHT');
    $(el).data('vx', -1 * $(el).data('vx'));
  }
  if (el.offsetTop <= 0 && $(el).data('vy') < 0) {
    //console.log('TOP');
    $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
  }
  if ((el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) >= bounding.offsetHeight) {
    //console.log('BOTTOM');
    $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
  }
}

function mover(el, bounding) {
  hitLR(el, bounding);
  el.style.left = el.offsetLeft + $(el).data('vx') + 'px';
  el.style.top = el.offsetTop + $(el).data('vy') + 'px';

}

function moveIt() {
  $('.bouncer').each(function() {
    mover(this, $('.bouncyHouse')[0]);
  });
}

moveInterval = setInterval(moveIt, 50);
$('button').on('click', function(){
 console.log(moveInterval);
 if( moveInterval != 0){
  clearInterval(moveInterval);
    moveInterval = 0;
  } else {
  moveInterval = setInterval(moveIt, 50);
  }
});
```

```css
.bouncyHouse {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.bouncer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
  left: 100px;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bouncyHouse">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>

  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='2' data-vy='-3'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='-2' data-vy='2'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='5' data-vy='2'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
</div>
```